# PrimeFaces push and EventBus problems

Tags: primefaces, push-notification

I have problems using primefaces push notification system:

-When i switched from pf 4.0 to 6.0/6.0.1/6.0.2 + atmosphere 2.4.3, my pushContext.push became deprecated and i experienced problem that facesmessage that i send are received as null on end point. (My preffered solution would be to get this to work)

-After that i tried using EventBus and method `EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();` always returns null. I tried the same example as on showcase. (It worked when i tried with PF 5.2 and Atmo 2.3.5, but i need pf 6.x release for my project)

This is the code:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class NotifyView {

    private final static String CHANNEL = "/notify";

    private String summary;

    private String detail;

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }
    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }
    public void setDetail(String detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public void send() {
        //line below makes NPE
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish(CHANNEL, new FacesMessage(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(summary), StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(detail)));
      }
     }
```

This is web.xml code related to push:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



And this is stack trace:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8qOU.png
```

Stack trace in text:

```
    `Aug 11, 2016 12:16:00 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: Received 'j`enter code here`ava.lang.NullPointerException' when invoking action listener '#{notifyView.send}' for component 'j_idt145'
Aug 11, 2016 12:16:00 PM javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener processAction
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mallocinc.ytm.webview.webtest.push.NotifyView.send(NotifyView.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.mallocinc.ytm.webview.filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.mallocinc.ytm.webview.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 11, 2016 12:16:00 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=j_idt141:j_idt145, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
Aug 11, 2016 12:16:00 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl log
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.mallocinc.ytm.webview.filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.mallocinc.ytm.webview.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mallocinc.ytm.webview.webtest.push.NotifyView.send(NotifyView.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)`
```

Comment: Code? In [mcve] format... and did you read other posts about this? Please use google, I've seen things like this before (container dependent)

Comment: I have tried other solutions without any luck and I've edited question with code now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: stacktraces in text/code please, not images.

Comment: I've added full stack trace in code now

Comment: any error before this? Like the push servlet not being started?

Comment: When i use PushContext.push() it finds socket and servlet but the received message through that method is empty, however when i use EventBus, i only get NPE.

Comment: PrimeFaces showcase 'injects' the eventbus. Did you try that? And are you sure there is not an 'old' jar hanging around in the webapp?

Comment: I didn't try that - can you please tell me what should i do in order to inject EventBus? Btw, i'm not using Maven, I'm using libraries (if that is relevant). And i dont have any old jars if i see right, Im using primefaces-6.0.2.jar and atmosphere-runtime-2.4.5.jar

Comment: You are using plain tomcat? No CDI? Then it is to cumbersome to install that I think (although you'd benefit from it). PF showcase uses Atmosphere 2.4.3, does 6.0.2 require 2.4.5? Can you try 2.4.3?

Comment: Im not using CDI, however everything worked with PF 5.2 and Atmosphere 2.3.5 , it stopped working after i've updated PF to 6.0+ so i guess that it can work without CDI. And i have tried PF 6.0+ Atmosphere 2.4.3 - no luck.

Comment: Then I'm for now clueless and I have no time to experiment, sorry. Maybe your Tomcat version plays some some role.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you upload a very minimal war somewhere? I read some older issues about push somewhere that are about this same issue, but that should not have worked with 5.3 either I think.

Comment: And can you post your server startup log? Do you see things like `22:00:50,607 INFO  [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport] (MSC service thread 1-5) JSR 356 Mapping path /primepush` or similar? And did you define endpoints? Via annotations?

Comment: I've found a solution and thank you for your help. It was crucial to check server startup log and see this : `3356 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation`. I needed `javax.inject` library in order to use `org.atmosphere.inject.InjectableObjectFactory` instead of `DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory` for dependency injection in order to evade NPE on EventBus. Thank you very much for your guidance.